# I get a blank screen while using HTML5 video player with JS when CSS is attached

Tags: javascript, html, css

I would like to show some video clips randomly on the screen, once at a time.
The site is working perfectly when I don't link any style sheets, including fonts but as soon as I link something video player goes blank even though source video is there.

Here's my code:
https://codepen.io/ondersumer07/pen/poJVdVp

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
  <title>Vinematik</title>
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Montserrat:400,700|Roboto:400,700&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
</head>

<body>
  <div class="grid-container">
    <h1 class="grid-header">Vinematik</h1>

    <div class="vid">



      <video class="grid-video" height="720" width="1280" controls>
        <source id="vsrc" />
        Please update your browser.
      </video>


    </div>

    <p class="grid-p"><i>Aykut Elmas</i> vine testi</p>
  </div>


  <script>
    document.getElementById("vsrc").src = Math.floor((Math.random() * 3) + 1) + ".mp4";
  </script>


</body>

</html>
```

Note:I take the videos from a folder, locally. They are named 1.mp4, 2.mp4, etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create Video Element like below.

```
<video class="grid-video" height="720" width="1280" controls id="videoEl">
        <source id="vsrc" type='video/mp4'/>
        Please update your browser.
</video>
```

Change your java script code like below.

```
document.getElementById("vsrc").src =  Math.floor((Math.random() * 3) + 1) + ".mp4";;
document.getElementById("videoEl").load();
```

Basically you need to load the video element once you set the source.

Comment: Thank you, it was my first time using the HTML video element. Didn't actually knew how to use it and couldn't find it. Thanks again!